# creating load balancer with container/ring of channels in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to make load balancer with container/ring of channels and I am having problems writing to them. Ring seems to take interface {} as type which causes problem when I try to write to it's assigned channel.

Error that comes out is

```
prog.go:11: invalid operation: chring.Value <- true (send to non-chan type interface {})
```

simplified code: http://play.golang.org/p/AJs2MV_UUC

```
package main

//import "fmt"
import "container/ring"

func main() {
    chring := ring.New(10)
    for i:=0;i<10;i++ {
        ch:=make(chan bool)
        chring.Value=ch
        chring.Value <- true //dies here
        chring = chring.Next()
    }   


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
chring.Value.(chan bool) <- true
```